# How do I increase font size in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new in Flutter+Dart and trying to increase font size but hard to understand documentation + implement to my work. Here is the file. How can I solve my problem?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(NewApp());



class NewApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('App Header'),
        ),
        body:  new Column(
          children: [
            new Container(
              margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: new Card(
                child: new Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: new Text('Hello Macaw'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the beginning this is hard to understand and implement. But once you understand, you will fall in love with the Flutter framework. Here is the solution:

```
new Text('Hello Macaw',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
```

After that, format the code. That's it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you Sir. Please give me some time to check @bQuiet

Comment: It's working Sir. Thank you so much and if I want to change the font color how do i do that?

Comment: Gload to heard. Please make sure you Mark my Answer for this question. And here is the **color** format  `new Text('Hello Macaw',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,fontSize: 16.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),`

Comment: Sure Sir. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `style` property of `Text` to change some of the property of the `Text`.

Example:

```
Text(
    "Your text",
     style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20.0,
      color: Colors.red,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
    ),
  )
```

It's a good practice to use predefined `style` for `Text` which gives you standard `fontSize` and `fontWeight` for the `Text`.

You can use them like this

```
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.XYZ
```

`XYZ` can be `body1`, `body2`, `title`, `subhead`, `headline` etc.